# iPhone: Settings > Safari > Databases no longer visible

Tags: iphone, ios

All,

I'm trying to see the local storage databases on my iPhone.

A variety of Google searches made this clear - if you go to "Settings", then "Safari" - you'll see a "Database" panel (just under "Accept Cookies...")

However, on MY iPhone - "Databases" is not listed.

I'm 99.9% sure that I HAVE databases on my phone:

1. I'm testing an HTML5 application that uses a database. According to the app, the database exists, and I can write to and read from it
2. I use Gmail through Safari - I'm *virtually certain* that it uses a database

I'm also virtually certain that I recall seeing the "Database" options in the past.

I just upgraded to iOS 4.3.5 - is it possible that this version moved the function to view the databases to someplace besides Settings > Safari? If so, where?

Or, is it a bug that the databases aren't getting displayed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting a little frustrated... I *knew* there were local safari databases on my phone, even though they weren't shown in the Settings > Safari panel.

So - as a last resort - I powered off my phone, and restarted. Sure enough, there they were, right where I expected them.